# Magento 1.9 admin and frontend always shows 404 not found

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, 404-page

Magento 1.9 admin and frontend always shows 404 not found

404 not found randomly shows when I'm on admin or on frontend but when I refreshed that certain 404 page it will work fine.

I tried reverting the .htaccess to its original code but it still exist. Tried also disabling/removing some extensions but no luck.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: check url when admin or frontend working and when 404 error comes.

Comment: @denish it is random.. when I clicked sometimes on an order or when I'm saving a product info change..

Comment: in url index.php/ is present when 404?

Comment: no its not present..

Comment: i think there is an issue

Comment: manually add index.php at that place

Comment: ok, will let you know once it shows again and I manually add it. thanks

Comment: system->configuration->web->search engine optimization change its value. and try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38945/discussion-between-mhel-and-denish-vachhani).

Comment: not possible because of working hours right now

Comment: my fault, when in admin the index.php is present but when it shows in front its not then when I just refresh the same url it will just load fine. I changed the Use Web Server Rewrites under SEO to No..

Comment: this solution works for you than i answer this.

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps:

1. Check if you are accessing the correct admin url (see `admin...frontName` node in `app/etc/local.xml` file)
2. Try to run the sql below:

```sql
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```